# Bazel installation on windows

Tags: windows, bazel

How to install Bazel on Windows 10? And how to run the command `bazel build`? 
Whenever I run the command `bazel build` it shows an error saying that it only works from workspace.
I don't know how to create a workspace.

Comment: It sounds like you have Bazel installed but you're not using it from within a Bazel project folder. What does your project folder structure look like? Perhaps you can try one of the tutorials on https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/getting-started.html to understand the basics on Bazel.

Comment: You need a WORKSPACE file (an empty file can be enough). You probably want to look at the tutorials to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty workspace file in your directory

```
copy NUL WORKSPACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Bazel considers a folder that contains a file named `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` (since Bazel 1.0.0) as a workspace. The `WORKSPACE` file can be empty.

The Bazel [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#packages_targets) (Bazel version 2.0.0) says about a workspace:

> A workspace is a directory on your filesystem that contains
>   the source files for the software you want to build, as well as
>   symbolic links to directories that contain the build outputs. Each
>   workspace directory has a text file named WORKSPACE which may be
>   empty, or may contain references to external dependencies required to
>   build the outputs.
>
> Directories containing a file called WORKSPACE are considered the root
>   of a workspace. Therefore, Bazel ignores any directory trees in a
>   workspace rooted at a subdirectory containing a WORKSPACE file (as
>   they form another workspace).
>
> Bazel also supports WORKSPACE.bazel file as an alias of WORKSPACE
>   file. If both files exist, WORKSPACE.bazel will take the priority.

Here is an example:

File/directory layout:

```
<directory> HelloWorld
├── <file> BUILD.bazel
├── <file> main.cpp
└── <file> WORKSPACE.bazel
```

*WORKSPACE.bazel*

```
workspace(name = "HelloWorld")
```

*BUILD.bazel*

```
cc_binary(
    name = "HelloWorld",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
)
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

**How to build on Windows?**

Open PowerShell and switch to the directory that contains the `WORKSPACE.bazel` file.

Type

```
bazel build //:HelloWorld
```

To run the application

```
bazel run //:HelloWorld
```

Details about how to install Bazel on Windows can be found [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/install-windows.html).